# How to draw a rectangle around inline text which contains a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I would like to draw a rectangle around a piece of text which itself contains subtext which is circles. How can this be achieved?

The circle around text is achieved using the following preamble:

```
\newcommand*{\circled}[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(C.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (C) {\vphantom{1g}#2};
        \node[draw, circle, inner sep=7.5pt, yshift=1pt] 
        at (C.center) {\vphantom{1g}};}}
```

The sample text to use is the following :

```
The state \rect{\circled{$ES_1$}, $ES_2, ES_3, ES_4$}, the initial state
```

where \rect would define a rectangle around the entire text within {}..

Or would there be some other way of achieving this without an additional \rect or \circ defined command?

Comment: Rectangle box you can draw as `\fbox`. For example: `The state \fbox{\circled{$ES_1$}, $ES_2, ES_3, ES_4$}, the initial state ...`, however, this has some limitation how to place in text. Please provide a sketch, what you like to have?

Comment: @Zarko that works, please add that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Though the solution is fine, I strongly recommend to not do this into a text paragraph because of the gap between the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of your boxed and circled text is not entirely clear to me, but you can try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\circled}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(C.base)]{
        \node[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt] (C) {\vphantom{1g}#1};}
                         }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
The state \fbox{\circled{$ES_1$}, $ES_2, ES_3, ES_4$}, the initial state ... \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]